# Access array in presto

Tags: sql, presto

We've a table named route_data and it has one of the main column named as start_hotspot_uuid , end_hotspot_uuid (INT) and another column we have is waypoints which has details for all the hotspot (it's an array and has multiple column inside it).

Now I'm trying to access the waypoint array to get the details of the start and end hotspot name by matching the start_hotspot_uuid = waypoints.hotspot_uuid then I want to get the name of the hotspot.

I'm doing something like

```
SELECT (
hb2b.capacity,
    rr.route_uuid,
    rr.readable_route_name,
    'Loop' as "Route Type",
    (
        SELECT name
        FROM UNNEST(rr.waypoints) AS w
        WHERE w.hotspot_uuid = route_data.start_hotspot_uuid
    ) AS start_hotspot_name,
    (
        SELECT name
        FROM UNNEST(rr.waypoints) AS w
        WHERE w.hotspot_uuid = route_data.end_hotspot_uuid
    ) AS end_hotspot_name,

from route_data
```

SHOW TABLE Output :

```
CREATE TABLE route_data (
   "route_uuid" varchar,
   "reverse_route_uuid" varchar,
   "city_id" integer,
   "city_name" varchar,
   "vehicle_view_id" bigint,
   "start_hotspot_uuid" varchar,
   "start_lat" double,
   "start_lng" double,
   "end_hotspot_uuid" varchar,
   "end_lat" double,
   "end_lng" double,
   "route_name" varchar,
   "readable_route_name" varchar,
   "category" varchar,
   "week_reference_start_time" timestamp,
   "schedule" array(row("hotspot_uuid" varchar, "start_day" double, "start_hour" double, "end_day" double, "end_hour" double, "interval" double, "min_interval" double, "max_interval" double, "rider_offset" double, "end_rider_offset" double)),
   "waypoints" array(row("hotspot_uuid" varchar, "is_entry_node" boolean, "bearing" integer, "latitude" double, "longitude" double, "name" varchar, "next_hotspot_uuids" array(varchar), "spot_index" integer, "next_hotspot_polyline" array(row("point_index" integer, "lat" double, "lng" double)), "next_stop_distance_meters" double, "next_stop_duration_seconds" double, "neighborhood" varchar, "point_of_interest" varchar, "secondary_point_of_interest" varchar)),
   "polyline" array(row("lat" double, "lng" double)),
   "route_distance_meters" double,
   "route_duration_seconds" double,
   "update_date" varchar,
   "organisation_uuid" varchar,
   "datestr" varchar
)
WITH (
   format = 'PARQUET',
   partitioned_by = ARRAY['datestr']
)
```

Sample Data (Words limit reach can't paste)

But getting an error that w.hotspot_uuid can't be resolved (there's no column name mistake)

Please help, I'm using pressto and stucked on this.

Comment: Please use the [SHOW CREATE table](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/show-create-table.html) statement on your table, and add the result to your question, together with some sample data, and expected output.

Comment: Please check, due to the words limitation can't paste sample data, but I've provided the info about what we are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [array functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#id3). For example you can use [`filter`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#filter) + accessing first element with [`element_at`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#element_at). Something along these lines (not tested since no sample data provided):

```sql
select -- ....
   element_at(filter(waypoints, r -> r.hotspot_uuid = start_hotspot_uuid), 1).name start_hotspot_name,
   element_at(filter(waypoints, r -> r.hotspot_uuid = end_hotspot_uuid), 1).name end_hotspot_name
from ...
```